# How to build a Picos affine expression?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, picos-api

I am using picos as a LP modeling language. However, I got the following inconsistency:

```
import picos as pic
prob_tmp = pic.Problem()
a_tmp = prob_tmp.add_variable("a",1)
eta_tmp = pic.new_param("eta",0.0341)
print (1-eta_tmp) * a_tmp
print a_tmp - eta_tmp * a_tmp
```

The `(1-eta_tmp) * a_tmp` and `a_tmp - eta_tmp * a_tmp` should mean the same thing. But the printed output is not corrected:

```
# (1 x 1)-affine expression: -eta + 1.0*a # <- this one is wrong!
# (1 x 1)-affine expression: a -eta*a #
```

Both of them should output `# (1 x 1)-affine expression: a -eta*a #`. Is it a bug? If so, how do I report that?

Comment: Not an answer to your problem per say, but have you tested [CVXPy](http://www.cvxpy.org/) I've used it for some LPs before with ease.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this is a bug, but only for the string representation of the expression. Internally, both expressions are stored correctly. To evidence this, let us give a `value` to the expression `a_tmp`. Then, printing the expressions show that they are both evaluated correctly:

```
> a_tmp.value = 42.
> print ((1-eta_tmp) * a_tmp)
40.5678
> print (a_tmp-eta_tmp*a_tmp)
40.5678
```

I will open an issue on gitlab to fix the string representation of `(1-eta_tmp) * a_tmp`